# Access kubernetes cluster details like namespaces and its pods and pod image using only REST API's

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster

I have my kubernetes cluster on ibm cloud account which i have access to.Using api key im able to generate IAM token(Bearer token) for authorization to use API's in this swagger `https://containers.cloud.ibm.com/global/swagger-global-api/` and get details till namespaces list.
But i need to still dig through namespaces and get pods of that and each pod image there.only using REST API/client libraries(no kubectl or commands).How would i achieve this from my external node application?

Comment: Can you access the standard [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) this way?  There's lots of information and several SDKs in the Kubernetes documentation.

Comment: In addition, [this doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_api_install#kube_api) shows how to access Kubernetes API.